# Polar plot Magnus effect not showing correct data

Tags: python, matplotlib, polar-coordinates

I wanted to plot the velocity equations of the flow around a rotating cylinder on a polar plot. (The equations are from "Fundamentals of Aerodynamics" by Andersen.) You can see the two equations inside the for loop statements.

I cannot for crying out loud manage to represent the calculated data onto the polar plot. I have tried every idea of mine, but arrived nowhere. I did check the data, and this one seems all correct, as it behaves how it should.

Here the code of my last attempt:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


RadiusColumn = 1.0
VelocityInfinity = 10.0
RPM_Columns         = 0.0#
ColumnOmega         = (2*np.pi*RPM_Columns)/(60)#rad/s
VortexStrength      = 2*np.pi*RadiusColumn**2 * ColumnOmega#rad m^2/s

NumberRadii = 6
NumberThetas = 19

theta = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,NumberThetas)
radius = np.linspace(RadiusColumn, 10 * RadiusColumn, NumberRadii)


f = plt.figure()
ax = f.add_subplot(111, polar=True)

for r in xrange(len(radius)):
    for t in xrange(len(theta)):


        VelocityRadius = (1.0 - (RadiusColumn**2/radius[r]**2)) * VelocityInfinity * np.cos(theta[t])
        VelocityTheta = - (1.0 + (RadiusColumn**2/radius[r]**2))* VelocityInfinity * np.sin(theta[t]) - (VortexStrength/(2*np.pi*radius[r]))
        TotalVelocity = np.linalg.norm((VelocityRadius, VelocityTheta))


        ax.quiver(theta[t], radius[r], theta[t] + VelocityTheta/TotalVelocity, radius[r] + VelocityRadius/TotalVelocity)


plt.show()
```

As you can see, I have set for now the RPMs to 0. That means that the flow should go from left to right, and be symmetric across the horizontal axis. (The flow should go around the cylinder the same way on both sides.) The result however looks more like this:

[image: Polar plot result - not correct!]

This is complete nonsense. There seems to be a vorticity, even when there is none set! Even weirder, when I only display data from 0 to pi/2, the flow changes!

[image: Polar plot result first quadrant - total mayhem]

As you can see from the code, I have tried to make use of unit vectors, but clearly this is not the way to go. I would appreciate any useful input.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic problem is that the `.quiver` method of a polar `Axes` object still expects its vector components in Cartesian coordinates, so you need to convert your theta and radial components to x and y yourself:

```
for r in range(len(radius)):
    for t in range(len(theta)):

        VelocityRadius = (1.0 - (RadiusColumn**2/radius[r]**2)) * VelocityInfinity * np.cos(theta[t])
        VelocityTheta = - (1.0 + (RadiusColumn**2/radius[r]**2))* VelocityInfinity * np.sin(theta[t]) - (VortexStrength/(2*np.pi*radius[r]))
        TotalVelocity = np.linalg.norm((VelocityRadius, VelocityTheta))

        ax.quiver(theta[t], radius[r],
                  VelocityRadius/TotalVelocity*np.cos(theta[t])
                  - VelocityTheta/TotalVelocity*np.sin(theta[t]),
                  VelocityRadius/TotalVelocity*np.sin(theta[t])
                  + VelocityTheta/TotalVelocity*np.cos(theta[t]))
    
plt.show()
```

[image: fixed figure]

However, you can improve your code a lot by making use of vectorization: you don't need to loop over each point to obtain what you need. So the equivalent of your code, but even clearer:

```
def pol2cart(th,v_th,v_r):
    """convert polar velocity components to Cartesian, return v_x,v_y"""

    return v_r*np.cos(th) - v_th*np.sin(th), v_r*np.sin(th) + v_th*np.cos(th)


theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, NumberThetas, endpoint=False)
radius = np.linspace(RadiusColumn, 10 * RadiusColumn, NumberRadii)[:,None]

f = plt.figure()
ax = f.add_subplot(111, polar=True)

VelocityRadius = (1.0 - (RadiusColumn**2/radius**2)) * VelocityInfinity * np.cos(theta)
VelocityTheta = - (1.0 + (RadiusColumn**2/radius**2))* VelocityInfinity * np.sin(theta) - (VortexStrength/(2*np.pi*radius))
TotalVelocity = np.linalg.norm([VelocityRadius, VelocityTheta],axis=0)

VelocityX,VelocityY = pol2cart(theta, VelocityTheta, VelocityRadius)

ax.quiver(theta, radius, VelocityX/TotalVelocity, VelocityY/TotalVelocity)

plt.show()
```

[image: fixed, vectorized final figure]

Few notable changes:

- I added `endpoint=False` to `theta`: since your function is periodic in `2*pi`, you don't need to plot the endpoints twice. Note that this means that currently you have more *visible* arrows; if you want the original behaviour I suggest that you decrease `NumberThetas` by one.
- I added `[:,None]` to `radius`: this will make it a 2d array, so later operations in the definition of the velocities will give you 2d arrays: different columns correspond to different angles, different rows correspond to different radii. `quiver` is compatible with array-valued input, so a single call to `quiver` will do your work.
- Since the velocities are now 2d arrays, we need to call `np.linalg.norm` on essentially a 3d array, but this works as expected if we specify an axis to work over.
- I defined the `pol2cart` auxiliary function to do the conversion from polar to Cartesian components; this is not necessary but it seems clearer to me this way.

Final remark: I suggest choosing shorter variable names, and ones that don't have CamelCase. That would probably make your coding faster too.

Comment: Wow! Thanks, this is great! I will go ahead and try out your suggestions. Only remark, I agree that writing out variable names takes more time, however personally, I find it makes the code also 10 times clearer. One year later, I read this and it will be like reading a story. Letter variables have been quite a nuisance for me. Anyways, thanks again, I will go over it.